# Enable and disabled Select in html form under condition

Tags: html, select

In my html form I have these *Select*:

```
<select size="1" name="First_Answer">                  
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option value="">----</option>
                  <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>

<select size="1" name="Second_Answer">                  
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option value="">----</option>
                  <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

In start page I need disabled the **select** Second_Answer.

I need enabled the **select** *Second_Answer* only when in the **select** *First_Answer* I have selected **No** value.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 01**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("select[name=First_Answer]").change(function(){
    var first_answer = $(this).val();

    if(first_answer == 'N')
    {
        $("select[name=Second_Answer]").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else
    {
        $("select[name=Second_Answer]").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
</script>

<select size="1" name="First_Answer">                  
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>

<select size="1" name="Second_Answer" disabled="disabled">                  
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select size="1" name="First_Answer">                  
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>

<select size="1" name="Second_Answer" disabled="disabled">                  
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=First_Answer]").change(function(){
        var first_answer = $(this).val();

        if(first_answer == 'N')
        {
            $("select[name=Second_Answer]").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else
        {
            $("select[name=Second_Answer]").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, in my first question I have posted **EDIT 01** this code with jquery not working in html form. The select Second_Answer is always disabled

Comment: You have to wrap this code on document ready. See the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<select size="1" name="First_Answer" id="First_Answer" onChange="onSelectChangeSB();">                  
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option value="">----</option>
                  <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>

<td id="outputSB"></td>
```

write javascript

```
<script>
function onSelectChangeSB()
{
   var dropdown = document.getElementById("First_Answer");
   var index = dropdown.selectedIndex;
   var ddVal = dropdown.options[index].value;
   if((ddVal == "N"))
   {
      outputSB='<select size="1" name="Second_Answer">                  
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="">----</option>
                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                <option value="N">No</option>
                </select>'; 
   }
   document.getElementById("outputSB").innerHTML = outputSB;
}
</script>
```